# How to filter a Pandas dataframe by timestamp functon using .query()

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-manipulation

I am trying to filter a Pandas df by dates (today and yesterday). For automation purposes I wish to filter using a timestamp function. This is pretty seamless in R:

```
df %>% 
  filter(date >= today() - 1)
```

However, my attempts to replicate in Pandas are not reaching any success so far:
Yesterday comes out fine, but .query() doesnt recognise it?

```
yesterday = (date.today() - timedelta(days=6)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df.\
   query('date >= yesterday')
```

Ideally I am seeking something all encompassing like:

```
df.\
   query('date >= (date.today() - timedelta(days=6)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')')
```

Comment: Why are you using a `timedelta(days=6)` (six days ago) in Python and comparing against grabbing *yesterday* (one day ago) in R?

Comment: Sorry, that's confusing and a typo. So for test purposes the data set I built meant the date variable ended 6 days ago. Sorry it seems a bit confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: `df.query('date >= @yesterday')`. You need `@` so pandas recognizes it's a variable.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you want to create an outside varible to use inside your query?

from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

`You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing them with an ‘@’ character like @a + b.`

using pandas only

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : pd.date_range('01-02-2020','01-03-2021',freq='D')})
df = df.set_index('date')

delta = (pd.Timestamp('today') - pd.DateOffset(days=1)).strftime('%d-%m-%y')

df.query(f"date <= @delta")

  date
  2020-01-02
  2020-01-03
  2020-01-04
  2020-01-05
  2020-01-06
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with string formatting:

```
df.query(f'date>= "{pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.Timedelta(days=6)}"')
```

Note: I tried with `pd.Timestamp` and `pd.Timedelta` but I'm sure it will work with `date` and `timedelta` as you used