# How to call a variable value in a query

Tags: python, dataframe

Simple question

How to call a variable value in a query

```
numerical_data.query('bpm >182.5 or bpm < 33')
```

I would like to use variable uf = 182.5 instead of having to define the value in the query.

The error i get is below. uf was defined prior to the query.

```
UndefinedVariableError: name 'uf' is not defined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter a Pandas dataframe by timestamp functon using .query()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60981168/how-to-filter-a-pandas-dataframe-by-timestamp-functon-using-query)

Comment: I have tried both numerical_data.query(f'bpm >{uf} or bpm < 33') and numerical_data.query(f'bpm >@uf or bpm < 33') as suggested but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but it can be work;

```
numerical_data.query('bpm >(%s) or bpm < 33',(uf))
```

Answer (score 1):

use `@myvariable` like this

```
numerical_data.query('bpm > @uf or bpm < 33')
```

Comment: wow I did not know this! I tried but it returns way more values than before it does not seem to be using the correct float number inside uf!

Comment: Sorry but I can't help out without having a look on a sample of your data.

Comment: whats the best way to share sample of the data. The dataset I am playing with is  (https://www.kaggle.com/cnic92/spotify-past-decades-songs-50s10s)

Comment: got it working! Thanks. `numerical_data.query('bpm >@uf or bpm < @lf')`